# Final sigmoid layer gives ValueError in Keras

Tags: python, keras

So, I have a set of MR images of size 32x32x32. I feed into a conv network. I however get an error in the final layer like this: 
**ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected activation_8 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (3, 24)** I have spent a good chunk of time trying to debug this error, but have been unsuccessful.

The crux of my code is shown below. I train the data using train_on_batch using a batch size of 24. Any pointers on what's going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
    def create_network():
      print 'Setting up first layer'
      model = Sequential()
      model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3, border_mode = 'valid', subsample 
      =      (1,1), init = 'glorot_uniform',input_shape = 
     (32,32,32),dim_ordering = 'th'))
     model.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.001, mode=2, axis=1, 
     momentum=0.99, weights=None, beta_init='zero', gamma_init='one', 
     gamma_regularizer=None, beta_regularizer=None))
     model.add(Activation('relu'))
     print 'First layer setup'

     print 'Setting up second layer'
     model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,border_mode = 'same', subsample = 
     (1,1),init = 'glorot_uniform'))
     model.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.001, mode=2, axis=1, 
     momentum=0.99, weights=None, beta_init='zero', gamma_init='one', 
     gamma_regularizer=None, beta_regularizer=None))
     model.add(Activation('relu'))
     model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2),strides = None))

     print 'Setting up third layer' 
     model.add(Convolution2D(64,3,3, border_mode = 'same', subsample = 
     (1,1), init = 'glorot_uniform'))
     model.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.001, mode=2, axis=1, 
     momentum=0.99, weights=None, beta_init='zero', gamma_init='one', 
     gamma_regularizer=None, beta_regularizer=None))
     model.add(Activation('relu'))

     model.add(Convolution2D(64,3,3, border_mode = 'same', subsample =  
     1,1), init = 'glorot_uniform'))
     model.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.001, mode=2, axis=1, 
     momentum=0.99, weights=None, beta_init='zero', gamma_init='one', 
     gamma_regularizer=None, beta_regularizer=None))
     model.add(Activation('relu'))
     model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2),strides = None))

     model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,border_mode = 'same',subsample = 
     (1,1),init = 'glorot_uniform'))
     model.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.001, mode=2, axis=1, 
     momentum=0.99, weights=None, beta_init='zero', gamma_init='one', 
     gamma_regularizer=None, beta_regularizer=None))
     model.add(Activation('relu'))

     model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,border_mode = 'same',subsample = 
     (1,1),init = 'glorot_uniform'))
     model.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.001, mode=2, axis=1, 
     momentum=0.99, weights=None, beta_init='zero', gamma_init='one', 
     gamma_regularizer=None, beta_regularizer=None))
     model.add(Activation('relu'))
     model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2),strides = None))

     model.add(Flatten()) 
     model.add(Dense(256))
     model.add(Activation('relu'))
     model.add(Dense(1))
     model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

     sgd = SGD(lr=1e-8, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
     model.compile(optimizer = 'sgd',loss 
     ='binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])
     return model

    if __name__ == "__main__":
       model = create_network()
       batch_size = 24
       X_train,y_train = load_train_data()
       for i in range(300):
        model.train_on_batch(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: This is probably coming from y_train. Can you print(y_train.shape) please? 2 other questions : why do you write batch_size=24, this is not used. And why do you fit in a loop instead of fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=300) ?

Comment: Printing y_train's shape gives me (24,). I was just experimenting with batch sizes. I think batch sizes should be in powers of 2. Regarding the last question, I have edited the code. I typed in the last line of code instead of copying it from the file.

Comment: Whats your default backend? I think the problem comes from there. What is keras version?